# Syntax error or access violation al agrupar consulta por mes o año, laravel 8

Tags: sql

estoy teniendo un problema al querer obtener cuantas veces se repite un dato (numero de ventas) en determinado tiempo, puedo obtenerlo diariamente agrupandolo por la fecha (sale_date):

```
$isStartDate = !is_null($start_date);
        $isEndDate = !is_null($end_date);
        $sales = DB::table('orders')->select("orders.sale_date",DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"),DB::raw("CONCAT_WS('-',MONTH(orders.sale_date),YEAR(orders.sale_date)) as monthyear"))
        ->when($isStartDate && $end_date, function ($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
            $query->whereBetween('orders.sale_date',[$start_date,$end_date]);
        },function ($query) {
            return $query
                    ->whereYear('orders.sale_date', '=', date("Y"));
        })
        ->groupBy("orders.sale_date");
```

(Este codigo me funcina y me arroja las ventas diarias).

Pero quiero agruparlo por mes o por año, en teoria es posible usando las funciones MONTH y o YEAR de mysql algo asi: `CONCAT_WS('-',MONTH(orders.sale_date),YEAR(orders.sale_date)) as monthyear`, he intentado poniendolo directamente en el group by o haciendo referencia a su nombre, de esta forma:

```
$isStartDate = !is_null($start_date);
        $isEndDate = !is_null($end_date);
        $sales = DB::table('orders')->select("orders.sale_date",DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"),DB::raw("CONCAT_WS('-',MONTH(orders.sale_date),YEAR(orders.sale_date)) as monthyear"))
        // ->join('orders','orders.id','=','productable_id')
        ->when($isStartDate && $end_date, function ($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
            $query->whereBetween('orders.sale_date',[$start_date,$end_date]);
        },function ($query) {
            return $query
                    ->whereYear('orders.sale_date', '=', date("Y"));
        })
        // ->whereIn('productable_type', [Order::class])
        ->groupBy("monthyear");
```

, pero obtengo el error de `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`, estoy conciente de que este error se puede evitar apagando el modo "strict" en el archivo config/database.php (lo probe y funciono), pero no quiero hacerlo de esa manera. Buscando en internet, en un foro alguien dijo lo siguiente:

- " The sensible solution would be to modify your query to abide by this rule (sometimes people store the main query inside a subquery so they can order the result by whatever they want). "

Pero no mostro ningun ejemplo, a que se refiere con esto? existe alguna otra forma de obtener lo que busco sin tener la necesidad de apagar el modo "strict"?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Revisa la otra pregunta, en la que se responde al error de tu código. Cuando usas `GROUP BY` en una consulta SQL debes indicar de algún modo cómo deben agruparse todas aquellas columnas que podrían arrojar resultados repetidos, sino el manejador se volvería loco preguntándose *¿cuál de todas debo entregar?* Por otra parte, tu consulta es extraña, por ejemplo, por qué seleccionas la fecha completa y también concatenada? Al fin y al cabo es el mismo dato, podrías seleccionarla como tal y luego darle formato desde el código PHP cuando vayas a usar los resultados.

Comment: @A.Cedano, disculpa, coloque el trozo de codigo donde concateno la fecha para hacer referencia a lo que escribi en mi pregunta

Comment: @BetaM, Gracias!, pero no responde a mi pregunta de que si es posible o no hacerlo de otra forma,o que significa lo de realizarlo con subqueries

Comment: Yo me refiero a que tú haces un select de la columna `orders.sale_date`  como tal, y luego intentas también hacer concatenaciones usando esa columna. Haz solamente el select de la columna y luego por programación extrae el mes, el año o lo que sea de ella. No sé si me explico. Prueba a quitar a la consulta la parte del `CONCAT_WS` y dinos se desaparece el error. Por otra parte, es importante que entiendas lo que te estamos diciendo sobre el `GROUP BY`. La pregunta enlazada responde al mensaje de error que tienes aquí, el cual ocurre por lo que te dije en el anterior comentario.

Comment: Intenta crear la primera parte de la variable `$sales` de este modo: `$sales=DB::table('orders')->select("orders.sale_date",DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"))` Ahí el error debería desaparecer.

Comment: @A.Cedano, hice la concatenacion para despues intentar usar el resultado en el groupby, solo tiene ese objetivo, no forma parte de mi consulta original, la consulta asi tal cual funciona bien, lo explico en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cómo para intentar usar el resultado en el `GROUP BY`? Eso no tiene sentido. ¿Lo que te interesa no es agrupar por la columna `orders.sale_date`? Una concatenación no tendría sentido aquí con respecto al `GROUP BY`. Esto te agrupa por la fecha, lo cual está bien: `->groupBy("orders.sale_date")` pero puede que la parte del `CONCAT_WS`, que no necesitarías para NADA, te esté fastidiando la consulta. No sé si me explico.

Comment: @A.Cedano, quiero agrupar por meses y por año usando la columna orders.sale_date, intenté concatenar para decirle que quiero agruparlos por meses y por años segun la columna sale_date, a lo que me refiero es que si dejo la consulta asi tal cual la muestro, y en el groupby, reemplazo el orders.sale_date por month_year, y desactivo el modo "strict", me arroja lo que yo quiero, es decir, las ventas por meses en cierto año, nose si me explico

Comment: Si quieres agrupar por meses y por años, intenta algo así. En la 1ª parte de la consulta: `$sales = DB::table('orders')->select(DB::raw("count(*) as cantidad_ventas"), MONTH(orders.sale_date) as month,YEAR(orders.sale_date) as year)` y en la parte del group by, pones esto: `->groupBy("month", "year");`

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias! me funciono, tenia que remover el campo sale_date, ahora entiendi de mejor manera esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select, muchas gracias de nuevo