# subconsulta solo se efectúa una vez

Tags: php, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo problemas con la columna que dice Cant. hasta fecha, ahi tendria qe mostrar el resultado segun la fecha, en el material chorrito con codigo 10101010 si lo muestra pero en los otros material solamente esta el espacio en blanco, que puedo agregar en el codigo sql para que pueda hacer la consulta correcta?.

```
$sql7= "SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas, 
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos mo WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' )) ) AS saldo, 
(SELECT m.cantidad FROM material AS m WHERE m.codigo = mo.codigo_material ) AS total, 
mo.fecha 
from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on uni.idunidad_medida = m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
                AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY m.codigo ASC";
```

Comment: Creo que su problema esá aqui -- AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) -- puede ser muchos donde identrada no es el máximo.

Comment: Donde obtienes el max te falta incluir `codigo_material`.

Comment: muy importante que leas esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359 tu query esta basicamente mal....

Comment: solamente seria de agregar al GROUP BY los SELECT que estan en el FROM_

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas, 
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas, 
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos mo WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN  '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59'  AND mo.codigo_material = m.codigo )) ) AS CantHastaFecha, 
m.cantidad,
mo.fecha 
from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on uni.idunidad_medida = m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i 00:00:00' 
AND '$fecha_f 23:59:59'
GROUP BY m.codigo ASC
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? una edicion? que es?

Comment: Es la respuesta brro

Comment: y como podemos saber que es una respuesta? que problema soluciona? donde estaba el problema? quien puede entender, ademas de vos, que soluciona y como lo soluciona? que partes de tu query modificaste? tene en cuenta, que la pregunta y la respuesta tiene que servirle a alguien mas... y tu group by, sigue estando mal....