# MYSQL - ROUND(AVG(valor)) solo me saca un registro

Tags: sql

Al realizar lo siguiente solo me da un resultado cuando hay bastantes mas.
Alguien se le ocurre el porque? Muchas gracias

```
Select 
   p.cdconcur as código,
   c.nombre,
   avg(round(p.puntos)) as media
from concursante c inner join participa p
on c.cdconcur = p.cdconcur
```

Comment: Porque estás sacando el promedio general...

Comment: Buenas, debes agregar un ejemplo de los valores obtenidos y cuales esperas obtener. AVG() por un lado, obtiene el promedio de los valores, por lo que devuelve solo1 registro.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No sabemos ni podemos saber porque ocurre eso. Tu query, es correcto, aunque sintacticamente este mal (mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)) ... sin datos, no podemos saber que te pasa.. tampoco sabemos porque deberia mostrarte solo uno...

Comment: Y q resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: Agrega al final un `group by p.cdconcur, c.nombre` creo que eso es lo que buscas. Un `select` con columnas no agregadas y sin `group by` es una aberración que solo `mysql` permite.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que falta agregar la clausula `GROUP BY` y el campo de tu funcion de agregacion `p.puntos`

```sql
Select 
   p.cdconcur as código,
   c.nombre,
   avg(round(p.puntos)) as media
from concursante c inner join participa p
on c.cdconcur = p.cdconcur
GROUP BY avg(round(p.puntos));
```

Pero sin saber el codigo de tus tablas, o los registros de las mismas, es dificil ver a ciencia cierta.

Comment: En todo caso, ¿no sería  `group by p.cdconcur, c.nombre`?

Comment: Jorge si la consulta es en SQL estándar no funcionará ya que debe cumplirse la regla de que los campos que no aparecen en el group by, deben aparecer en el select con una función de agregación, y esa regla tu consulta no la cumple, si es en MySql puede que funcione ya que MySql viola el SQL estándar y hace lo que le da la gana. Revisa esto para que entiendas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select

Comment: Efectivamente se trataba del group by ,añadiendolo y modificando la query:                                                             
  ` Select  c.nombre, round(avg (p.puntos),2) as 'media de puntos'
from concursante c inner join participa p on c.cdconcur = p.cdconcur
group by c.nombre order by avg (p.puntos)  desc;`                                                           Muchas gracias!