# Error al hacer una consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

les comento, tengo 2 hosting uno con motor: mariadb y otro con mysql y en el motor con mariaDB mi codigo funciona correctamente:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(RD.precio * RD.unidades),0) AS subtotal,R.condicion, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(',RD.unidades,') ',P.producto) SEPARATOR ' - ') AS productos, R.frac_mpadicional AS mp_adicional, RD.*,R.fecha_reg,R.id_reporte,R.medio_pago,R.abono,R.credito, C.nombre AS cliente FROM reportes_detalle RD LEFT JOIN reportes R ON R.id_reporte = RD.id_reporte LEFT JOIN clientes C ON C.id_cliente = R.id_cliente LEFT JOIN productos P ON P.id_producto = RD.id_producto WHERE R.id_cliente = 705 GROUP BY RD.id_reporte ORDER BY RD.id_reporte DESC LIMIT 0,300
```

pero al ejecutar este mismo comando en mi otro hosting con motor mysql me muestra el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es: que opcion tengo para solucionar este problema; y si en caso mi consulta mysql esta mal elaborada cual es el error ?

Nota:

1. se que segun muestra la imagen se podria corregir modificando mi mysql pero al ser un hosting compartido me rijo a las configuracion de mi proveedor.
2. la idea seria migrarme de mysql a mariadb pero no puedo por la misma razon de la 1
3. cabe recalcar que todo el sistema (php, mysql,etc) corre perfectamente en mi primer hosting (mariadb) pero en el otro (mysql) no.

Aca las caracteristicas de mis hosting:
hosting donde si funciona todo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hosting donde tengo el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema es [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359) y si arreglas un query, se arregla todo...

Comment: @gbianchi si amigo, gracias