# como puedo contar los meses que son consecutivos Mysql

Tags: mysql

como puedo contar los meses consecutivos es decir si un registro de un cliente tiene compras en enero y febrero se cuenta como 2, pero si los registros no son consecutivos por mese es decir enero y marzo por ejemplo no los cuente actualmente los estoy contando asi.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(VentaFecha))
```

Este es la consulta completa

```
  SELECT 
    CURRENT_DATE() FECHA_REFERENCIA,
    FAZ.DESC_REGION REGION,
    P.ID,
    P.TarjetaID TARJETA, 
    P.PacienteCedula CEDULA, 
    P.PacienteNombre NOMBRE, 
    P.PacienteApellido APELLIDO,
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.PacienteApellido, ' ', 2) = 'DE LA' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.PacienteApellido, ' ', 3)
        WHEN LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.PacienteApellido, ' ', 1)) < 4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.PacienteApellido, ' ', 2)
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.PacienteApellido, ' ', 1)
    END PRIMER_APELLIDO,
    CONCAT(P.PacienteNombre,' ',P.PacienteApellido) NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
    P.PacienteCelular CELULAR,
    P.PacienteTelefono TELEFONO,
    CASE
        WHEN P.PacienteCelular = '' THEN P.PacienteTelefono
        WHEN P.PacienteCelular = '809-999-9999' THEN P.PacienteTelefono
        WHEN P.PacienteCelular = '809' THEN P.PacienteTelefono
        WHEN P.PacienteCelular = '809-000-0000' THEN P.PacienteTelefono
        ELSE P.PacienteCelular
    END TEL_COMBINADO,
    IFNULL(D.DoctorNombre,'NINGUNO') DOCTOR,
    P.PacFechaAfiliacion FECHA_AFILIACION,
    CASE WHEN D.DoctorID IS NULL or TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, P.UltimaModificacion, CURRENT_DATE()) >=6
           THEN 'NO'
           ELSE 'SI'
    END AS ACTUALIZADO,
    "ALERTA COMPRA" ESTATUS,
    ROUND(SUM(V.VentaCantidad)) CANTIDAD,
    SUM(V.VentaTotal) MONTO,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(VentaFecha)) CANT_MESES
    FROM paciente P
    JOIN venta V ON V.TarjetaID = P.TarjetaID
    LEFT JOIN paciente_producto PP on PP.TarjetaID=P.TarjetaID
    LEFT JOIN doctor D ON D.DoctorID = P.MedicoTratante
    LEFT JOIN paciente_zonificacion PZ on PZ.TarjetaID = P.TarjetaID
    LEFT  JOIN provincia PR ON PR.ID = PZ.Provincia
    LEFT  JOIN (SELECT CD_PROVINCIA, DESC_PROVINCIA , DESC_REGION
          FROM farmacias_zonificacion GROUP BY CD_PROVINCIA, DESC_PROVINCIA, DESC_REGION) FAZ
          ON FAZ.CD_PROVINCIA= PR.id_provincia_sap
    WHERE V.VentaFecha BETWEEN finicial AND ffinal
    GROUP BY P.ID, P.TarjetaID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(VentaFecha)) >1
    ORDER BY P.TarjetaID
```

Por ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la tabla la ultima columna indica cuantos meses el cliente ha comprado continuamente es decir compro dos meses seguidos

Comment: Esto es mysql no? tu query, esta mal.. mira por favor [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359).. ahora, que queres que cuente? que meses? si compro en enero, febrero y luego en abril, mayo y junio.. que tiene que contar? si compro en diciembre y enero? tu planteo, no tiene mucha logica, o le falta definicion...

Comment: La idea en si es mostrar los registros donde las fechas por meses son continuas por meses, actualmente lo tengo donde hay mas de 1 compra en alguno de los meses,

Comment: no entiendo lo que decis... agrega ejemplos claros donde veamos los casos que queres... inclui todos los escenarios... no me explicaste que hacer en el caso que te nombre yo...

Comment: osea la columna que quiere es una que diga el numero de meses que un cliente ha comprado en meses seguidos. y en ese caso también debería contarse, ya que pues 12 (diciembre)  deberia seguirle el 1 pero no se si debería ser así.

Comment: y si compra en dos tandas de meses salteados, cuanto queres contar? no estas siendo nada claro... y por lo que decis, no necesitas un query, necesitas un proceso que haga estos calculos...

Comment: simplemente no debería mostrarse

Comment: Bueno.. que yo sepa, (y no termino de entender lo que necesitas) lo que pedis requiere un proceso, no un query... pero capaz tenes mas suerte con alguien mas..

Comment: ¿Si agrupas por cliente y luego filtras por mes?

Comment: No creo que no se puede tiene que hacer un proceso diferente