# Limitar dentro del grupo en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo esta consulta MySQL:

```
SELECT articulo.id_articulo, articulo, precio, fecha 
FROM articulo INNER JOIN precio ON articulo.id_articulo = precio.id_articulo 
WHERE '$fecha' >= fecha 
GROUP BY articulo.id_articulo, precio 
ORDER BY articulo, precio ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

Lo que necesito es una salida como esto, en la cual se límite el tamaño de los registros dentro de un grupo:

```
id_articulo articulo       precio fecha
 1          Bolsa de Agua  17     12-30-2017
 1          Bolsa de Agua  12     15-05-2021
 2          Hielo 4kg      10     12-30-2017
 2          Hielo 4kg      12     12-30-2017
 2          Hielo 4kg      15     20-07-2021
 3          Hielo 15kg     11     12-30-2017
 3          Hielo 15kg     15     08-04-2018
 3          Hielo 15kg     18     15-10-2020
 3          Hielo 15kg     21     15-10-2021
```

Cómo puedo lograr eso?

Comment: cual es la idea de esta consulta??? el group by no hace nada distinto a un distinct, y para colmo, es incorrecto... miara [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la agrupación dentro de una subconsulta

```sql
SELECT articulo.id_articulo, articulo, precio, fecha
FROM
   articulo INNER JOIN (SELECT precio, precio.id_articulo FROM precio WHERE articulo.id_articulo = precio.id_articulo ORDER BY precio ASC LIMIT 5) precio_2 ON articulo.id_articulo = precio.id_articulo 
WHERE '$fecha' >= fecha 
GROUP BY articulo.id_articulo, precio 
ORDER BY articulo, precio ASC
```

Comment: Eso.. no agrupa.. eso selecciona los 5 precios mayores... en realidad la consulta que muestra OP no tiene ningun sentido, porque no hace nada con el group by...