# Sistema encuestas con valor para cada usuario, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, mysql-workbench

Actualmente tengo un sistema de encuestas que esta por usuario, todo bien puedo votar bien y me muestra un grafico realizado en **Chart.js** que muestra cuantos respondieron las preguntas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que me pidieron realizar una modificación con respecto a la votación, que es agregándole un valor a cada usuario, por ejemplo tengo 3 usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces por ejemplo si en la pregunta solo vota **Jorge** y no votan los demás, como el es el que tiene mas valor, solo con que vote el ya tiene mas del 50% y por ende se aprueba la pregunta con la opción que el elija, y el grafico mostraría un 60% de solo el voto de **Jorge**

Supongo que esto se validaría en el query que llena la grafica, el cual es el siguiente

```
SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta, preguntas.titulo,COUNT('preguntas.titulo') as count, opciones.valor 
                  FROM opciones 
                  INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
                  INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
                  WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = '$id_pregunta' 
                  GROUP BY opciones.valor 
                  ORDER BY preguntas.id_pregunta
```

Y dentro de la tabla de Usuarios, se agregaria un campo que diga Valor, y se le colocarian los valores a cada usuario que estos seran fijos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este sentido seria modificar la consulta? sin embargo no se como iría para obtener el resultado que quiero

Alguien que me ayude

Comment: Es como vos decis.. necesitas una tabla de valor.. ya cada voto no vale 1... vale lo que le pongas...

Comment: pero en caso de tener la tabla y valores asignados, como seria la consulta y evaluar los valores que asigne

Comment: en lugar de count, harias un sum de los valores que tiene cada usuario.. como nota, tu query anda bien solo en mysql, pero en realidad esta mal.. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)