# No me funciona GROUP BY en laravel/eloquent

Tags: sql

No consigo que me funcione una consulta con GROUP BY en eloquent

Tengo esta tabla, llamada likes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
$likes = Like::orderBy('user_id')->get();
    foreach($likes as $like) {
        var_dump($like->user_id);
    }
```

Me muestra los resultados correctamente, en total 8 resultados ordenados por user_id (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6). Pero no quiero que me repita las filas 2, 3 ni 5.

Esto es lo que quiero poner:

```
select * from `likes` group by `user_id`
```

Pero lo quiero poner en eloquent, así que lo pongo de esta forma:

```
$likes = Like::groupBy('user_id')->get();
    foreach($likes as $like) {
        var_dump($like->user_id);
    }
```

Pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hago la consulta adecuadamente en eloquent?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: No mucho. En el ejemplo del enlace si cambio el nombre de la categoría de "a" a "d", al hacer de nuevo la consulta debería obtener como resultado en la columna nombrecategoría "d, d, d" y no "a, a, d", entonces el nombre de la categoría resultante sería "d". No se cómo aplicar lo que explican en ese enlace para cambiar mi consulta eloquent y me de el mismo resultado que la consulta sql

Comment: Ya me funciona, deshabilitando el modo estricto en el fichero config/database y sin tocar la consulta eloquent que ya tengo... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104412/what-is-the-use-of-strict-in-laravel-config-database