# obtener la ultima fecha de los registros sql

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos.

Tabla 1 - public_usu

| id | correo | telefono | pais |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario@gmail.com | 987654321 | chile |
| 2 | usuario2@gmail.com | 987654322 | chile |

y por otro lado otra tabla - reg_pagos

| id_pago | id_usu | fecha_r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 1 | 2019-10-19 16:26:51 |
| 000002 | 1 | 2019-11-11 11:58:46 |
| 000003 | 1 | 2019-11-28 13:26:53 |

Si tengo estas tablas y estos registro e intento realizar

```
SELECT 
p.id, p.correo, p.telefono, p.pais, MAX(r.fecha_r) AS "ultimoPago", 
COUNT(r.fecha_r) as contarPagos 
FROM public_usu p  
LEFT JOIN reg_pagos r on p.id=r.id_usu 
WHERE p.pais = "Chile" 
AND r.fecha_r BETWEEN '2019-10-19 11:51:24' AND '2021-12-27 01:01:01' 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY contarPagos ASC
```

obtengo algo como esto

| id | correo | telefono | pais | fecha_r | npagos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario@gmail.com | 987654321 | chile | 2019-11-11 11:58:46 | 3 |

Aquí el problema, no me está regresando el ultimo pago registrado dentro de la fecha. Entonces, si el usuario hizo un pago en una fecha dentro o por fuera de las fechas, trae sus registro.

Lo que necesito es encontrar el ultimo registro hecho por el usuario que esté dentro de las fechas requeridas. Si su ultimo registro está por fuera del rango de fechas, entonces no me muestres los datos del usuario.

Agradezco cualquier aporte

Comment: Los valores dentro de la columna `fecha_r` no tienen formato `DATETIME`, por lo que seria necesario que añadas la definición de las tablas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Misma pregunta de Marcos. CUáles son los tipos de datos en las columnas? Y estamos seguros que esa es la consulta? (p.pais = Chile no va con los datos del ejemplo, es para confirmar)

Comment: Revisa que el campo "fecha" tenga el formato Datetime y que los datos que contengas en esta columna  "fecha" al menos cumplan con el formato YYYY-MM-DD o en su defecto YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss  para que cuando utilices el BETWEEN  te interprete de manera correcta la información.

Comment: Si esa columna no es tipo DATETIME y no está formateada como **YYYY-MM-DD** vas a tener serios problemas de resultados impredecibles: Haciendo una simple comparación string: `'2022-4-18' > '2022-12-15'`, da `true` (`4` es mayor que `1[2]`), lo cual para nuestra lógica es incorrecto pero el sistema lo ve perfectamente bien. Arregla el tipo de dato de la columna o que tenga el formato adecuado.

Comment: "Si su ultimo registro está por fuera del rango de fechas, entonces no me muestres los datos del usuario." no entiendo esto.. tu consulta no va a devolver nada? va a devolver un registro nulo? de igual forma, no estas aclarando que base de datos es (y supongo que todos creemos que es mysql, porque tu group by [esta mal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359))... de paso, esto ultimo, para lo que queres hacer, es realmetne importante...

Comment: Hay algo que no cuadra en todo esto. ¿Cómo puede existir una fecha así `2019-6-32`? No tiene ningún sentido!

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez eso ya fue corregido. error de transcripción del problema

Comment: He simulado tu planteamiento acá http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e895e/1 y obtengo sin problemas el último pago. Creo que tu problema está en que estás trabajando con strings. Revísa el enlace y me dices.

Comment: @gbianchi al agrupar por `id` se está asegurando que habrá un solo correo, un solo teléfono y un solo país en la agrupación, así que su ` group by` funcionará de manera correcta.

Comment: Nada que nos compartes los tipos de dato de las columnas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez eso es falso. mira el post que hice al respecto... Puede que funcione, pero no es correcto...

Comment: @gbianchi Tu post se refiere a una misma tabla, y acá estamos hablando de dos tablas diferentes. Si estoy agrupando por id de usuario, no hay manera de que tenga dos correo o dos nombres por grupo. Entiendo el punto que explicas, pero no es el caso.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez siempre y cuando, id sea unico (que suponemos es el caso). de cualquier forma, esto solo funciona en mysql y con las versiones anteriores. En las ultimas viene desactivado por defecto.

Comment: Agrupar por Primary Key siempre te asegurará que tendrás los campos únicos en la agrupación pertenecientes a la tabla que contiene el primary key. No veo como el id no puede ser único. De cualquier manera, no vale la pena discutir por ello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que describes, requieres obtener los usuarios cuya **última fecha de pago** esté en el rango de fechas describes.

Para ello selecciona primero los usuarios y agrúpalos por `id`. Luego con un `HAVING` filtras los grupos de usuarios cuyos últimos pagos estén en el rango de fechas requerido. La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.correo, p.telefono, p.pais, MAX(r.fecha_r) AS "ultimoPago",
    COUNT(r.fecha_r) as contarPagos
FROM public_usu p
         JOIN reg_pagos r on p.id=r.id_usu
WHERE p.pais = 'chile'
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING MAX(r.fecha_r) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-10-19 11:51:24', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND  STR_TO_DATE('2021-12-27 01:01:01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
ORDER BY contarPagos ASC
```

---

He simulado tu entorno [acá](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08362a/2) creando las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public_usu(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  correo VARCHAR(50),
  telefono VARCHAR(9),
  pais VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg_pagos(
  id_pago INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_usu INT,
  fecha_r DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_usu) REFERENCES public_usu(id)
);

INSERT INTO public_usu(correo, telefono, pais) VALUES ('usuario@gmail.com', '987654321', 'chile');
INSERT INTO public_usu(correo, telefono, pais) VALUES ('usuario2@gmail.com', '987654322', 'chile');

INSERT INTO reg_pagos(id_usu, fecha_r) VALUES (1,STR_TO_DATE('2019-10-19 16:26:51', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
INSERT INTO reg_pagos(id_usu, fecha_r) VALUES (1,STR_TO_DATE('2019-11-11 11:58:46', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
INSERT INTO reg_pagos(id_usu, fecha_r) VALUES (1,STR_TO_DATE('2020-06-30 13:26:53', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```

Y obteniendo el último pago con la consulta que te adjunté me arroja:

| id | correo | telefono | pais | ultimoPago | contarPagos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario@gmail.com | 987654321 | chile | 2020-06-30 13:26:53 | 3 |

---

Comment: He podrido visualizar en que me estoy equivocando, sin embargo aun no encuentro una solución. Tomando el entorno que has creado, añade al los registros esto INSERT INTO reg_pagos(id_usu, fecha_r) VALUES (1,STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-23 13:26:53', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')); INSERT INTO reg_pagos(id_usu, fecha_r) VALUES (2,STR_TO_DATE('2021-11-23', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));

Comment: Ahora para explicarme mejor, lo que quiero es que la consulta solo me considere el ultimo registro que ha hecho el usuario. En el caso del usuario 1, la ultima consullta la habría hecho el 2022-02-23 13:26:53. Esta fecha está fuera del rango esperado entonces no debería mostrarse los datos de este usuario en la consulta. Lo que necesito es que en estos casos, la consulta me considere solo esa ultima fecha.

Comment: Creo que ahora más o menos te sigo. Quieres los registros de los usuarios cuya última consulta esté en ese rango.

Comment: Exacto. lo que se me pide es clasificar a los usuario. Por un lado debo encontrar a los usuarios que tienen mas de 3 meses sin registrar un pago y por otro lado debo encontrar a los usuarios que tienen por lo menos un registro estos últimos tres meses.

Comment: @Lilibeth checa la consulta que te puse en la sección EDIT y dime si eso es lo que quieres. Si es eso, edito con la explicación correspondiente.

Comment: Siiiii, justo esto era lo que necesitaba. Me salvaste la vida! Jaja muchisimas gracias. Me llevo algo que aprender de esto.

Comment: Solo para la próxima, eso que hice yo en SQL Fiddle, trata de adjuntarlo tú para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Me alegra te haya servido.