# Buscar cuántas veces se repite un campo en un intervalo de tiempo

Tags: sql, date

sigo jugando con SQL y ahora estaba intentando encontrar una forma en donde la consulta que haga me responda ¿cuántas veces se repitió X en N tiempo? Ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla con el nombre de Usuario, la bebida que compró y la fecha en donde la compró

| Usuario | Bebida | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | Coca | 2022-01-/01 |
| Maria | Coca | 2022-01-01 |
| Maria | Coca | 2022-01-03 |
| Maria | 7up | 2022-02-02 |
| Juan | Coca | 2022-01-01 |
| Juan | Coca | 2022-01-01 |
| Juan | 7up | 2022-05-05 |
| Alan | Coca | 2022-02-02 |
| Alan | Manaos | 2023-08-08 |
| etc | etc | etc |

¿Qué personas compraron "Coca" al menos dos veces en menos de 30 días?. Entonces, con esa pregunta la querry me debería de devolver lo siguiente:

| usuario | Contador |
| --- | --- |
| Maria | 3 |
| Juan | 2 |

(si es que no erré los datos de mi tabla, je)

Entonces, suponiendo que la tabla se llama "MiTabla":

```
select * 
ó
Select Usuario, Fecha, Bebida,  count(*) as 'Contador'
from MiTabla
where Bebida= 'Coca'
group by Usuarios, Bebida
having count(*) >= 2 
order by Usuarios
```

En teoría, con eso m debería de devolver todos los usarios que tengan dos o más "Coca", pero con tiempo "histórico", entonces empecé a agregarle a esa querry cosas como:

```
where Fecha::date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-02-01'
```

También:

```
<= dateadd(day, 30, '2022-01-01')
```

Pero en todo me tiraba distinto error. Aclaro que esto lo pongo, si no entiendo mal lo que escribo a continuación del "where Bebida= 'Coca'", ejemplo.

```
select * 
ó
Select Usuario, Fecha, Bebida,  count(*) as 'Contador'
from MiTabla
where Bebida= 'Coca'  <= dateadd(day, 30, '2022-01-01')
group by Usuarios, Bebida
having count(*) >= 2 
order by Usuarios
```

Asique nada, si alguien tiene alguna idea cuál/es es mi error se lo agradecería! Intenté buscar la respuesta pero me aparecían publicaciones como [estas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195561/sql-having-between-a-date-range) las cuales, si no lo entendí mal, no es lo que busco
(no sería hermoso si existiese un if y restar las fechas? Para mi si, je)

Comment: estas usando mysql no? igual todas las querys que estas mostrando tienen errores de forma...

Comment: Es en Snowflag, el cual creo que si, usa mysql.

Cuáles serían esos errores?

Comment: para empezar, tus group by estan mal.. [mira aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)... luego, estan mal los querys en si, la forma... en tal caso, si usas Snowflag, eso tendria que estar aclarado.. sql es un lenguaje generico, pero por ejemplo, esto: fecha::date no es valido en sql...

Comment: Uh, ahora me voy a fijar. En el trabajo me dieron acceso a snow para que vaya "jugando" con tablas y aprendiendo, asique me creé esta que publiqué pero estoy seguro que de alguna manera al menos la idea me había salido (no la query del intervalo de fecha) y usé fecha::date between '..' and '...' para otras cosas...mmm, tendré que volver a chequearlo 

Igualmente, sacando esos errores, en si estaba yendo para el lugar correcto para responder mi pregunta o estoy totalmente equivocado?

Comment: El principal error es que en `WHERE` estás usando un campo que no existe, Usuario**s** (con S). Corrigiendo eso y poniendo `... AND Fecha BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-01' ...` ya debe funcionar.

Comment: No funciona, lo escribi asi:
Select Usuario, Fecha, Bebida,  count(*) as 'Contador'
from MiTabla
where Bebida= 'Coca' 
group by Usuario, Fecha, Bebida
having count(*) >= 2 
and Fecha between '.....' and '......'

Y el resultado queda en blanco, no aparece nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides puede tomarse de distintas formas para definir los intervalos. Pueden ser intervalos predefinidos en el sistema, a partir de la primera fecha de la tabla, a partir de la primera fecha de cada usuario y bebida, o intervalos que se sobrepongan dependiendo de la fecha de cada fila.

En este caso, dejo un ejemplo de como hacer el último caso. Tomo la fecha de cada compra y luego veo cuantas compras hubo en los siguientes 30 días (incluyendo el actual).

```
--Generamos los datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE MiTabla(
    Usuario varchar(10),
    Bebida  varchar(10),
    Fecha   date);
INSERT INTO MiTabla
VALUES
( 'Maria', 'Coca  ', '2022-01-01'),
( 'Maria', 'Coca  ', '2022-01-01'),
( 'Maria', 'Coca  ', '2022-01-03'),
( 'Maria', '7up   ', '2022-02-02'),
( 'Juan',  'Coca  ', '2022-01-01'),
( 'Juan',  'Coca  ', '2022-01-01'),
( 'Juan',  '7up   ', '2022-05-05'),
( 'Alan',  'Coca  ', '2022-02-02'),
( 'Alan',  'Manaos', '2023-08-08');

/*Aquí inicia la solución*/

--Hacemos un pre-agregado por fecha
WITH cteCompras AS(
    SELECT Usuario, 
           Fecha, 
           Bebida,  
           COUNT(*) Cuantos
    FROM MiTabla
    GROUP BY Usuario, 
           Fecha, 
           Bebida
)
SELECT T.Usuario, 
       --Dejo las fechas de inicio y fin del intervalo para validar los datos
       T.Fecha AS fechaInicio, 
       DATEADD( DD, 29, t.Fecha) AS FechaFin,
       T.Bebida,  
       ctos.Cuantos
FROM cteCompras T
--La siguiente instrucción nos permite hacer referencias a las tablas anteriores dentro de una subconsulta.
CROSS APPLY( SELECT SUM(Cuantos) Cuantos --Sumamos las compras del día
            FROM cteCompras c
            WHERE t.Usuario = c.Usuario --Cuando el usuario y la bebida correspondan
            AND t.Bebida = c.Bebida
            AND c.Fecha BETWEEN t.Fecha AND DATEADD( DD, 29, t.Fecha) --Dentro de un intervalo de 30 días
            HAVING SUM(Cuantos) > 1) ctos; --Y solo regresamos cuando haya más de uno

GO --Por último, limpio mi base de datos
DROP TABLE MiTabla
```

Comment: Mmm algo claramente estoy haciendo mal, pero muchas gracias igual por tu respuesta! La voy a estudiar ya que hay algunas cosas que no estaría entendiendo.

Gracias.

Comment: Cualquier duda que tengas del código, pregunta para dejarlo claro.