# MIN DE MYSQL AGRUPADO

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola necesito traer el mínimo de una fila de acuerdo a la columna prioridad, pero cuando le doy min y lo agrupo solo me trae el mínimo de la prioridad pero no me trae el resto de columnas los campos que deben de ir, el código es el siguiente.

```sql
SELECT id_registro,
       fecha,
       hora,
       dia,
       anio,
       semana,
       intervalo,
       nombre_dia,
       mes,
       tipo_documento,
       documento,
       nivel_1,
       nivel_2,
       MIN(prioridad) AS prioridad       
FROM BD.TB tgf
GROUP BY Placa
```

Comment: en el `group by` tiene que ser un campo que le estés haciendo `select`, por lo que veo Placa no es un campo que tengas integrado en tu `select`, has una prueba agrupando por `id_registro` a ver si te funciona como quieres

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Cuando genero el group by de una vez identifica un registro y no me lo cambia con el min, me mantiene el mismo registro, con el Id_Registro no funciono tampoco.

Comment: No aún así no se como poder solucionarlo.

Comment: mira, ese MIN(prioridad) solo trae un registro y es normal, lo demás de tu select regresa varios registros, tu necesitas regresar solo un registro? si es asi entonces mete una cláusula Where en donde la condición sea que prioridad = MIN(prioridad)

Answer (score 0):

Así te debería resultar:

```sql
SELECT id_registro,
       fecha,
       hora,
       dia,
       anio,
       semana,
       intervalo,
       nombre_dia,
       mes,
       tipo_documento,
       documento,
       nivel_1,
       nivel_2,
       prioridad 
FROM BD.TB tgf
WHERE prioridad = ( select min(prioridad)
                    from BD.TB tgf2 )
```

Suponiendo claro que aquí te bote un registro único:

```sql
select min(prioridad)
from BD.TB tgf2
```

Es decir, si hay varios campos con ese valor mínimo, entonces tu output será todos aquellos registros con ese valor mínimo.