# GROUP BY, ORDER BY en consulta POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

No estoy consiguiendo hacer que funcione esta consulta.

```
SELECT 
trecetasini.fecha, trecetasini.hora, 
trecetasini.idreceta, trecetasini.valtagint as valdtintinc, 
trecetasfin.valtagint as valdtintfin, 
trecetasini.valtagflot as valdtfloint, 
trecetasfin.valtagflot as valdtflotfin, 
trecetasfin.nombretag 
FROM trecetasfin, trecetasini 
WHERE trecetasfin.idreceta  = trecetasini.idreceta 
AND trecetasini.fecha BETWEEN '2011-01-25'::date AND '2011-01-25'::date
GROUP BY trecetasini.fecha 
ORDER BY trecetasini.hora;
```

Al ejecutar la consulta da el siguiente error:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: la columna «trecetasini.hora» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación
  Position: 27
```

Agrego la columna que indica el mensaje de error sin embargo al volver a ejecutar manda otro error para agregar otra columna y asi sucesivamente pide agregar otra y otra columna, tal parece que esta pidiendo agregar todas las columnas sin embargo no necesito agrupar por todos los campos de ambas tablas.

Buscando en internet encontré este [ejemplo](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/joining-with-group-by-and-order-by.php), lo adapté a mi requerimiento, sin embargo tampoco funcionó.

Las tablas son muy simples, básicamente son iguales:

```
==DATOS INICIALES==trecetasini
idtabla
fecha
hora
idreceta
dirtag
valtagint
valtagflot
nombretag

==DATOS FINALES==trecetasfin
idtabla
fecha
hora
idreceta
dirtag
valtagint
valtagflot
nombretag
```

De un controlador programable recibe datos iniciales y después de completar su rutina guarda los datos finales; la consulta es para comparar los datos inicial y final, una vez que el usuario seleccione un parámetro de fechas.

¿Tal vez estoy redundando innecesariamente en dos tablas que son iguales?, sin embargo ¿cómo podría distinguir los datos inicial y final si guardo todo en una sola tabla?

Comment: ¿A qué te referís con "no funciona"? ¿Da un error? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y lee [ask].

Comment: ¿De casualidad has intentado con `GROUP BY trecetasini.fecha, trecetasini.hora` ?

Comment: Seguro que esa es la consulta? Ese error sale cuando en el select tienes una función de agregación (count, max, sum, avg,...) sobre algún campo, lo que demanda que agrupe por los campos en el select que no se usan en dicha función. Si esa es la consulta que arroja ese error, ¿qué pasa si quitas la condición between?

Comment: Y que queres mostrar en esas columnas que no queres agrupar???? todas las columnas que no son de una funcion de agrupacion tienen que ir en el select, si no, como sabe que poner en esas columnas?? lee sobre el tema [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por su colaboracion, despues de varios intentos consegui hacer funcionar la consulta, como dije necesitaba comparar los valores inicial y final en base al campo idreceta que ambas tablas tienen y en base a un parametro de fechas:

```
SELECT trecetasini.fecha, trecetasini.hora, trecetasini.idreceta, trecetasini.valtagint as valdtintinc, trecetasfin.valtagint as valdtintfin, trecetasini.valtagflot as valdtfloint, trecetasfin.valtagflot as valdtflotfin, trecetasfin.nombretag 
FROM trecetasfin, trecetasini 
WHERE trecetasfin.idreceta  = trecetasini.idreceta AND trecetasini.fecha BETWEEN '2022-07-05'::date AND '2022-07-05'::date 
ORDER BY trecetasini.fecha, trecetasini.hora;
```

Esto por ahora funciona para mi.

Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Al final, no estás respondiendo a tu propia pregunta. ¿Qué pasó del `GROUP BY`? Por otra parte, lectura recomendada: Las consultas que se te hicieron son para buscar la mejor solución a tu problema. [Deberías responderlas para obtener respuestas de calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/).