# Agrupar registros de consulta Mysql sin usar GROUP BY y ordenar por fecha reciente

Tags: mysql, orderby, inner

Buen día. Estoy intentando ordenar por fecha de venta mas reciente y luego agrupar por nombre de cliente los registros de dos tablas relacionadas

Son dos tablas, una llamada 'clientes' y otra 'ventas'

clientes

### id ---    nombre ---  teléfono

### 1 ---     Carlos ---  300111111

### 2 ---     Andres ---  300111111

Ventas

### id ---     id_cliente  producto  fecha

### 1 ---          1 ---        reloj ---  22-08-22

### 2 ---          1 ---        mesa ---   10-08-22

### 3 ---          2 ---        mesa ---   20-08-22

### 4 ---          2  ---       lapiz --- 15-08-22

Tengo la siguiente consulta Mysql:

```
  select clientes.*, ventas.producto from clientes
  inner join ventas
  on
  clientes.id= ventas.id_clientes
  where ventas.fecha = (select max(ventas.fecha))
  order by ventas.fecha desc
```

obtengo esto:

### nombre ---  producto ---   fecha

### carlos ---   reloj ---    22-08-22

### andres ---   mesa ---     20-08-22

### andres ---   lapiz ---    15-08-22

### carlos ---   mesa ---     10-08-22

Efectivamente ordena por fecha, pero ahora necesito agrupar por nombre. si lo hago utilizando GROUP BY me arroja:

```
  select clientes.*, ventas.producto from clientes
  inner join ventas
  on
  clientes.id= ventas.id_clientes
  where ventas.fecha = (select max(ventas.fecha))
  group by ventas.nombre
  order by ventas.fecha desc
```

### nombre ---  producto ---   fecha

### carlos ---   mesa ---    10-08-22

### andres ---   lapiz ---    15-08-22

Me agrupa pero por fecha mas antigua, ya que el uso de GROUP BY arroja el primer registro

Lo que necesito es:

### nombre ---  producto ---   fecha

### carlos ---   reloj---     22-08-22

### andres ---   mesa---    20-08-22

Comment: ¿Por qué dices sin usar `GROUP BY`? ¿Porque no te sale o porque alguien te impide usarlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En realidad, te agrupa como quiere, porque tu group by no incluye todas las filas... mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Comment: si quisieras la ultima fecha, deberias usar max(fecha) y esa funcion de agrupacion (que para eso sirve el group by) te va a traer la ultima...

Comment: ¿Te has planteado que pasaría si Carlos hubiera comprado sus dos artículos el mismo día? ¿Querrías que aparecieran dos líneas o todo en una?

Comment: Amplío la respuesta analizando esa posibilidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta es un poco complicada porque hay que resolverla en tres pasos:

a) Obtener la última fecha de compra de cada cliente:

```
SELECT id_cliente,
  MAX(fecha) fecha
  FROM ventas
  GROUP BY 1;
```

b) Obtener los artículos que compró en esa fecha:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ventas
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cliente,
      MAX(fecha) fecha
      FROM ventas
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_cliente,fecha)
```

c) Y, finalmente, obtener el nombre de ese cliente:

```
SELECT nombre,producto,c1.fecha
  FROM ventas
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_cliente,
      MAX(fecha) fecha
      FROM ventas
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_cliente,fecha)
  JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=id_cliente;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(15),
  telefono varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE ventas(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_cliente int,
  producto varchar(15),
  fecha date
  );
INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, telefono) VALUES
('carlos',300111111),('andrés',300111111);
INSERT INTO ventas (id_cliente, producto, fecha) VALUES
  (1,'reloj','2022-08-22'),
  (1,'mesa','2022-08-10'),
  (2,'mesa','2022-08-20'),
  (2,'lápiz','2022-08-15');
```

Obtendrás el resultado que esperabas:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| nombre  | producto | fecha      |
+---------+----------+------------+
| carlos  | reloj    | 2022-08-22 |
| andrés  | mesa     | 2022-08-20 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

¿Te has planteado que pasaría si Carlos hubiera comprado sus dos artículos el mismo día? Vamos a comprobarlo con:

```
UPDATE ventas set fecha='2022-08-22' WHERE id=2;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| nombre  | producto | fecha      |
+---------+----------+------------+
| carlos  | reloj    | 2022-08-22 |
| carlos  | mesa     | 2022-08-22 |
| andrés  | mesa     | 2022-08-20 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Como, probablemente, lo que quieras es que aparezcan todos los productos en la misma línea, sin duplicar nombres, habría que añadir un agrupamiento extra:

```
SELECT nombre,producto,fecha FROM (
    SELECT id_cliente,fecha,
      GROUP_CONCAT(producto) producto
      FROM ventas
      JOIN (
        SELECT id_cliente,
          MAX(fecha) fecha
          FROM ventas
          GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1 USING(id_cliente,fecha)
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c2 JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=id_cliente;
```

Para obtener:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| nombre  | producto   | fecha      |
+---------+------------+------------+
| carlos  | reloj,mesa | 2022-08-22 |
| andrés  | mesa       | 2022-08-20 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Espero que te resulte útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para mejorar la repuesta.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente. Muchas gracias....