# Integrar cláusula where; es consulta inner join como condición campo avg(precio) agrupado por nombre fabricante

Tags: sql

Les dejo la siguiente consulta que no consigo que me funcione según el enunciado del ejercicio (me falta por encajar la condición precio medio producto por fabricante mayor a 200€):

ENUNCIADO

> Muestra el precio máximo, precio mínimo, precio medio y el número total de productos de los fabricantes que tienen un precio medio superior a 200€. No es necesario mostrar el nombre del fabricante, con el código del fabricante es suficiente.

Instrucción desarrollada a falta de encajar cláusula where

```
SELECT FABRICANTE.NOMBRE, FABRICANTE.CODIGO, MAX(PRODUCTO.PRECIO) AS PRODUCTO_MAS_CARO_FABRICANTE, MIN(PRODUCTO.PRECIO) AS PRODUCTO_MAS_BARATO_FABRICANTE, ROUND(AVG(PRODUCTO.PRECIO),2) AS PRECIO_MEDIO_POR_FABRICANTE, COUNT(PRODUCTO.CODIGO_FABRICANTE) AS PRODUCTOS_FABRICANTE_MAYOR_200 
FROM FABRICANTE  
INNER JOIN PRODUCTO ON FABRICANTE.CODIGO=PRODUCTO.CODIGO_FABRICANTE 
GROUP BY FABRICANTE.NOMBRE*;
```

También adjunto captura de las 2 tablas relacionadas

[image: tabla producto]

[image: tabla fabricante]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el resultado esperado y el obtenido. Además, pon parte de los resultados de esas consultas _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask]. Por último... No es necesario gritar :)

Comment: NO GRITES. No es necesario; entendemos a las buenas :D

Comment: dos cosas.. mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359).. y solo te falta la clausula having!!!! con eso, listo todo!