# Mysql Union all y group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema con una consulta en la que uso union all para unir 3 querys. Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT A AS hora, B AS '-1semana', C AS '-2semana', D AS '-3semana'
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS C, NULL AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, NULL AS C, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
) 
AS X ORDER BY hora
```

Y devuelve estos datos:

```
hora    -1semana  -2semana  -3semana  
------  --------  --------  ----------
08:00          1    (NULL)      (NULL)
10:00     (NULL)         2      (NULL)
11:00          3    (NULL)      (NULL)
11:00     (NULL)    (NULL)           7
14:00     (NULL)    (NULL)          12
14:00     (NULL)         2      (NULL)
15:00     (NULL)         1      (NULL)
15:00     (NULL)    (NULL)           5
16:00     (NULL)    (NULL)           1
```

El problema está en que tengo datos que comparten la misma hora, por lo que decidí agregar un group by al final de la consulta (AS X GROUP BY hora ORDER BY hora) y ahí es donde los datos cambian y no se agrupan bien

```
SELECT A AS hora, B AS '-1semana', C AS '-2semana', D AS '-3semana'
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS C, NULL AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, NULL AS C, COUNT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H')) AS D
FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE(fecha),1), TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), YEAR(DATE(fecha)), WEEK(DATE(fecha),1)
) 
AS X GROUP BY A ORDER BY A
```

```
hora    -1semana  -2semana  -3semana  
------  --------  --------  ----------
08:00          1    (NULL)      (NULL)
10:00     (NULL)         2      (NULL)
11:00          3    (NULL)      (NULL)
14:00     (NULL)         2      (NULL)
15:00     (NULL)         1      (NULL)
16:00     (NULL)    (NULL)           1
```

Las horas si se agrupan pero se pierden datos de una columna, si en las anteriores ya se ocupó esa fila por decirlo de alguna manera.

Comment: Como escribiste ese group by?

Comment: @gbianchi ya modifiqué la pregunta y agregué eso. Simplemente agregué el "GROUP BY A" al final del query

Comment: y entonces, tu respuesta esta [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)... como esperas que sepa que poner en cada columna si no se lo especificas?

Comment: El problema que tengo es que al añadir todos los campos del SELCET al GROUP BY, sigue mostrando horas duplicadas, es decir, me mantiene las agrupaciones de cada subquery pero no me hace una en general.
En palabras cortas, me muestra los mismos datos que la consulta sin agrupar.

Comment: porque en lugar de agregar todos los campos al select, tenes que aplicar alguna funcion de agregacion para los otros campos, no para los que queres agrupar (tus horas) si no para los otros

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, llevaba un par de días en eso y realmente me ayudaste con los comentarios!

Comment: Comparti tu respuesta con todos una vez que lo hayas solucionado

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la ayuda que recibí logré solucionar el problema. Lo que hice fue que quité los COUNT que tenía dentro de cada subquery y los agregué al SELECT general.
Con eso si se hizo el GROUP BY como lo esperaba, acá muestro la consulta y el resultado obtenido:

```
SELECT A AS hora, COUNT(B) AS 'semana1', COUNT(C) AS 'semana2', COUNT(D) AS 'semana3'
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H') AS B, NULL AS C, NULL AS D
    FROM llamadas WHERE WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H') AS C, NULL AS D
    FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H'), ':00') AS A, NULL AS B, NULL AS C, TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H') AS D
    FROM llamadas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND WEEK(fecha) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
) 
AS X GROUP BY A ORDER BY A

hora    semana1  semana2  semana3  
------  -------  -------  ---------
08:00         0        1          0
10:00         0        0          2
11:00         0        3          0
14:00         0        0          2
15:00         0        0          1
```