# ¿Cómo agrupar el ultimo registro con group by usando inner joins? (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Buen día compañer@s, es por si me pueden ayudar con un problema que se me presenta al momento de realizar un group by; y es que no se como agruparlo por el registro más reciente por el campo en la tabla que intento agruparlo, a continuación pondren la consulta (es un poco extensa pero es fácil de entender).

La consulta en resumen lo que busca, es buscar todos los exámenes que tenga un curso y decirme cual fue la nota en cada examen para el curso.

Consulta sin group by:

```
SELECT mc.idmodulo_conferencia as idCurso, mc.dsnombre_modulo as nombreCurso,
mc2.idmodulo_conferencia as idModuloCurso,
c.idconferencia as idEvalaucion, c.dsnombre_conferencia as nombreEvaluacion,
cer.idconferencia_evaluacion_resultado as idResultado, cer.dspuntuacion as puntajeExamen, cer.femodificacion as fechaCalificacion,
if(mcc.id != NULL, "Si", "No") as completo, if(mcc.certifica != NULL, mcc.certifica, "No") as certifica, mcc.fecha as fechaCertifica
from modulo_conferencia mc 
inner join modulo_conferencia mc2 on mc.idmodulo_conferencia = mc2.idmodulo_padre 
inner join conferencia_modulo_conferencia cmc on mc2.idmodulo_conferencia = cmc.idmodulo_conferencia 
inner join conferencia c on cmc.idconferencia = c.idconferencia
inner join config_evaluaciones ce on c.idconferencia = ce.idconferencia 
left join conferencia_evaluacion_resultados cer on ce.idconferencia = cer.idconferencia 
left join usuarios_web uw on cer.idusuario_web = uw.idusuario_web 
left join modulo_conferencia_completado mcc on mc.idmodulo_conferencia = mcc.idmodulo
where mc.idmodulo_conferencia = 1
and uw.idusuario_web = 30246
order by cer.idconferencia_evaluacion_resultado desc
```

Salida de la consulta sin group by:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como nos damos cuenta en la imagen nos dice que un usuario realizo dos veces una evaluación ya que esta la perdió. **La idea es que agrupemos los datos de las evaluaciones para que así usando la fecha nos tome el ultimo resultado de la evaluación que el realizo.** Pero lo que ocurre es que si le colocamos un group by por el id de la evaluación siempre me saca la evaluación más vieja y no la más reciente, como se mostrara en la siguiente imagen.

Setencia con el group by:

```
SELECT mc.idmodulo_conferencia as idCurso, mc.dsnombre_modulo as nombreCurso,
mc2.idmodulo_conferencia as idModuloCurso,
c.idconferencia as idEvalaucion, c.dsnombre_conferencia as nombreEvaluacion,
cer.idconferencia_evaluacion_resultado as idResultado, cer.dspuntuacion as puntajeExamen, cer.femodificacion as fechaCalificacion,
if(mcc.id != NULL, "Si", "No") as completo, if(mcc.certifica != NULL, mcc.certifica, "No") as certifica, mcc.fecha as fechaCertifica
from modulo_conferencia mc 
inner join modulo_conferencia mc2 on mc.idmodulo_conferencia = mc2.idmodulo_padre 
inner join conferencia_modulo_conferencia cmc on mc2.idmodulo_conferencia = cmc.idmodulo_conferencia 
inner join conferencia c on cmc.idconferencia = c.idconferencia
inner join config_evaluaciones ce on c.idconferencia = ce.idconferencia 
left join conferencia_evaluacion_resultados cer on ce.idconferencia = cer.idconferencia 
left join usuarios_web uw on cer.idusuario_web = uw.idusuario_web 
left join modulo_conferencia_completado mcc on mc.idmodulo_conferencia = mcc.idmodulo
where mc.idmodulo_conferencia = 1
and uw.idusuario_web = 30246
group by cer.idconferencia, c.dsnombre_conferencia 
order by cer.idconferencia_evaluacion_resultado desc
```

Imagen de la salida de la sentencia con el group by:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final agradecería que me ayudaran con este problema, una forma fácil para saber si el resultado es el correcto es que en la evaluación de conocimientos 1, su puntaje sea 33 y no el 0.

Comment: tu respuesta esta [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Comment: @gbianchi el ejemplo que me pasas esta excelente, explica bastante las causas del problema y dice que para solucionarlo se pueden usar una función de agregación. ¿Sabes como puedo agregar una función de agregación para mi caso?

Comment: Habria que desarmar toda tu consulta, agrupar en los momentos indicados y luego agregar toda la informacion extra. No es algo que te pueda indicar a la ligera, hay que conocer el modelo de datos. Mi recomendacion es que logres primero traer el dato que vos queres, y despues agregues toda la otra informacion necesaria. Probablemente tengas que usar subconsultas...

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero tengo una ultima pregunta, en el ejemplo que tu pones como harías para seleccionar la categoría D en vez de la A?

Comment: usando la funcion que mas te convenga segun la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html).. supongo que en ese caso sera un MAX

Comment: Ojo.. tal vez en este caso tan complejo, te convenga usar una funcion ventana...

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: si usas esto seria mas facil ayudarte: http://sqlfiddle.com/