# Group by PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Contexto: Tengo una vista que se del Left Join de 2 tablas Tabla A con registros unicos y Tabla B con muchos registros pero asociados a la tabla A.

Ejemplo: Registro de Tabla A con id 123 y en la tabla B hay 5 registros con ese mismo id asociado el 123.

Lo que necesito es agrupar la información por ese id que tienen en común.

En MySQL mi consulta es muy sencilla, es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(COLUMNA) AS ConteoPlanes From Tablavista Group By Id;
```

El problema:

El problema es que en Postgres me pide poner las columnas del `SELECT` en el `GROUP BY` y de hacerlo me da más registros, me manda filas duplicadas.

Entonces no sé como podría solucionar la situación.

Comment: Has probado poner comillas? por ejemplo cuando el campo de tu tables es `id_persona` no necesitas poner comillas, pero cuando es `Id_Persona` entonces si necesitas poner las comillas quedaría así `SELECT * FROM "Personas" WHERE "Id_Persona" = 1`

Comment: Es que cuando usas `GROUP BY` debes indicar al SGBD qué hacer con aquellas columnas que podrían estar repetidas en el grupo. Por eso no puedes hacer un `SELECT *` a no ser que incluyas todas las columnas en el `GROUP BY`. Define en primer lugar qué columnas quieres entre todas y las que pueden ser repetidas ponlas con una función de agregación, `MAX()`, `MIN()` u otra o ponlas en la lista del `GROUP BY`. MySQL funciona a veces sin eso, pero es una permisividad contraria al espíritu de las bases de datos y no deberías acostumbrarte a ella.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Es que MySQL [_lo hacía mal de entrada_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359) :) Por cierto, edita tu pregunta para aclarar esta oración "Tengo una vista que se del Left Join de 2 tablas" (...) De hecho, [hay varias preguntas en el sitio](/search?q=group+by+%5Bpostgresql%5D) relacionadas a esta.