# Consulta a tres tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql

muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda

Tengo 3 tablas en mysql

Clientes: Id, nombre, apellido, DNI, Prefijo, Tfno, email, Direccion, CodPostal, poblacion, provincia, pais, Observaciones

Relación 1:N clientes |---< contratos

Contratos: id, total_contrato, observaciones, cliente_id

Relación 1:N contratos |---< pagos

Pagos: id, fecha, pago_realizado, comprobante, observaciones, contratos_id

Un cliente puede tener varios contratos y un contrato puede tener varios pagos porque no tiene por qué ser pagado de una sola vez.

Quiero hacer una consulta para saber la suma total de los importes de los contratos que tiene un cliente y también saber los pagos que ha ido realizando sobre el total de los contratos que tiene.

Estoy haciendo esta consulta pero me suma varias veces el importe de un contrato si tiene más de un pago.

```
SELECT 
    clientes.Id,
    clientes.nombre,
    clientes.apellido,
    contratos.id,
    sum(contratos.total_a_devolver),
    sum(pago_realizado)
FROM contratos 
INNER JOIN pagos ON contratos.Id = pagos.contratos_id
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.Id = contratos.clientes _id
WHERE clientes.Id = 1;
```

A ver si algún alma caritativa puede decirme por qué me duplica los resultados, es como si hiciera un bucle y pasara más de una vez por el mismo sitio pero no soy capaz de dar con la tecla.

Muchas gracias

edito la pregunta para introducir un set de configuración de las tablas y datos para las mismas

```
CREATE DATABASE `inversores_gt7` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */;

CREATE TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Clientes` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `total_contrato` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL,
  `cliente_id` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `pago_realizado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `contratos_id` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

—— RELACIONES —— 
ALTER TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` 
ADD INDEX `clientes_contratos_idx` (`cliente_id` ASC);
;
ALTER TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `clientes_contratos`
  FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_id`)
  REFERENCES `prueba_contratos`.`Clientes` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` 
ADD INDEX `contratos_pagos_idx` (`contratos_id` ASC);
;
ALTER TABLE `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `contratos_pagos`
  FOREIGN KEY (`contratos_id`)
  REFERENCES `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (`ID`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;


—— INTRODUCIR DATOS —— 
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Clientes` (`nombre`, `apellido`) VALUES ('jesus', 'gomez');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Clientes` (`nombre`, `apellido`) VALUES ('luis', 'vazquez');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Clientes` (`nombre`, `apellido`) VALUES ('juan’,’martinez’);

INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (‘total_contrato`,`cliente_id`) VALUES (‘5000’,’1’);
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (‘total_contrato`,`cliente_id`) VALUES (‘5000’,’1’);
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (‘total_contrato`,`cliente_id`) VALUES (‘7000’,’2’);
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (‘total_contrato`,`cliente_id`) VALUES (‘8000’,’2’);
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Contratos` (‘total_contrato`,`cliente_id`) VALUES (‘20000’,’3’);


INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('1000', '1');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '1');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('500', '2');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('3500', '2');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('3000', '3');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2000', '4');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('5000', '4');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '5');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '5');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '5');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '5');
INSERT INTO `prueba_contratos`.`Pagos` (`pago_realizado`, `contratos_id`) VALUES ('2500', '5');
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es tener la suma de todos los contratos de un mismo cliente y todos los pagos que se han realizado a los contratos de ese cliente, para así poder calcular el porcentaje que le falta por pagar a ese cliente. Edito mi pregunta con dos consultas que he realizado de forma separada para saber si de alguna forma se pueden unir y así ya tendría el resultado esperado.

Consulta A para calcular el total de contratos de cada cliente.

```
SELECT cliente_id, sum(total_contrato) 
FROM prueba_contratos.Contratos
group by cliente_id;
```

Consulta B para calcular los pagos realizados a cada contrato.

```
SELECT contratos_id, sum(pago_realizado) 
FROM prueba_contratos.Pagos
group by contratos_id;
```

Con esto tendría el total de los contratos de cada cliente y los pagos que han realizado. Me gustaría unirlas para saber cuánto ha en total cada cliente y poder calcular el porcentaje que le queda por pagar.

Muchas gracias

Comment: te los duplica basicamente porque primero la consulta selecciona todos los registros, y como las relaciones son 1 a n, entonces trae todos los mismos campos por todos los pagos que tengas, y luego de eso hace la suma (no lo hace asi, pero para que se entienda el con como esta, suma todo).. igual, mysql te deja hacer eso y no es correcto... mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Comment: he probado a agruparlo por cliente, contrato o pago, y nada. Creo que debería hacer primero una consulta donde aparezcan todos los pagos de los contratos y después otra que muestre los contratos de los clientes, pero me pierdo, no se cómo hacerlo

Comment: pensalo mas facil.. saca los sum.. fijate que trae.. y de ahi, pensa que datos queres sumar.. y cuales no...

Comment: gracias, pero sigo probando todas las combinaciones posibles y no soy capaz de resolverlo

Comment: en lugar de sum, traete el max(contratos.total_a_devolver) ;)

Comment: me devuelve el valor máximo, pero no el total

Comment: agrega un set de datos minimo y un ejemplo para que podamos ayudarte mas...

Comment: he editado mi pregunta con datos para poder hacer la tabla y ver si me podéis ayudar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay una forma de unir las dos consultas que pasaste , y es insertando el `query` 1 en una temporal , y el siguiente en otra temporal ,y después uniendolas con un `Left join`

Quedaría de este modo:

```
Select * into ##tempo1 from (
SELECT cliente_id, sum(total_contrato) as Sum_contrato
FROM prueba_contratos.Contratos
group by cliente_id)a


Select * into ##tempo2 from (
SELECT contratos_id, sum(pago_realizado) as Sum_pagos
FROM prueba_contratos.Pagos
group by contratos_id)b

Select fact_table.cliente_id, fact_table.Sum_contrato,
T2.Sum_pagos
from ##tempo1 fact_table
Left join ##tempo2 t2 on fact_table.cliente_id= t2.cliente_id
Group by fact_table.cliente_id
```

Esa es una posible solución.

Comment: ok, gracias, voy a probarlo y te cuento, muchas gracias

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias, he adaptado un poco el código para que funcionara bien y en el tempo2 lo he agrupado por cliente_id y no por contratos_id para que me sume todos los pagos realizados aun mismo cliente.
Voy a editar mi pregunta para que veáis cómo queda el código. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

suponiendo que total_a_devolver sea total_contratos, es simplemente agrupar como corresponde... Como el total es siempre igual para todos, lo agregas en la condicion de agrupacion, asi como el id de contrato y listo, y solo sumas los pagos.

```
SELECT 
    clientes.Id,
    clientes.nombre,
    clientes.apellido,
    contratos.id,
    contratos.total_a_devolver
    sum(pago_realizado)
FROM contratos 
INNER JOIN pagos ON contratos.Id = pagos.contratos_id
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.Id = contratos.clientes _id
WHERE clientes.Id = 1
group by 
    clientes.Id,
    clientes.nombre,
    clientes.apellido,
    contratos.id,
    contratos.total_a_devolver
```

Comment: Lo que me gustaría hacer es tener la suma de todos los contratos de un mismo cliente y todos los pagos que se han realizado a los contratos de ese cliente, para así poder calcular el porcentaje que le falta por pagar a ese cliente. Edito mi pregunta con dos consultas que he realizado de forma separada para saber si de alguna forma se pueden unir y así ya tendría el resultado esperado, muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces la query es un poquito mas complicada, hay que usar funciones ventana (OVER) ademas del group by, para que ajuste cada parte por separado por como tenes armada tu base @ajmd97

Comment: Muchas gracias, investigaré eso de los OVER que es, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @ajmd97 las ediciones son para mejorar el contenido de las respuestas o preguntas (formato de código, correcciones ortográficas/de tipeo, etc.), no para responder a las preguntas. En todo caso, si la solución que le diste a tu problema difiere de alguna de las propuestas que tenés acá, redactá vos mismo una nueva respuesta.

Comment: ok, entendido, la próxima vez lo haré así. Muchas gracias