# Consulta + subconsulta + group by + order by

Tags: mysql, join, subconsultas, group-by, orderby

Tengo estas dos tablas y esta consulta. El resultado no es el esperado ya que no me trae el último estado de cada presupuesto.

Tabla presupuestos: (contiene mas campos, por simplicidad muestro los relevantes)

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | validez             |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2022-09-01 11:56:47 |
|  2 | 2022-06-15 13:45:12 |
|  3 | 2022-12-18 07:32:14 |
| 13 | 2022-12-29 11:56:47 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Tabla de estados de presupuestos:

```
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| id | idPresupuesto | idEstado | fecha               | observaciones              |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 36 |             1 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |                            |
| 37 |             2 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |                            |
| 58 |             2 |        6 | 2022-12-27 22:05:10 | actualización automática   |
| 38 |             3 |        1 | 2022-12-15 07:32:14 |                            |
| 39 |             3 |        2 | 2022-12-26 22:49:06 |                            |
| 29 |            13 |        1 | 2022-12-26 11:56:47 |                            |
| 30 |            13 |        2 | 2022-12-26 12:04:27 |                            |
| 33 |            13 |        3 | 2022-12-26 13:09:11 |                            |
+----+---------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Consulta:

```
select p.id, estado.idEstado, estado.fecha
from presupuestos p
inner join (
        select idPresupuesto, idEstado, fecha
        from presupuestos_estado
        order by fecha desc
    ) as estado on estado.idPresupuesto = p.id 
where (estado.idEstado <= 3) and (timediff(p.validez, now()) < 0)
group by estado.idPresupuesto;
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | idEstado | fecha               |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |
|  2 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |
|  3 |        1 | 2022-12-15 07:32:14 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

Resultado deseado:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | idEstado | fecha               |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |
|  3 |        2 | 2022-12-26 22:49:06 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

El resultado deseado debe traer los presupuestos cuya fecha de validez haya sido superada y cuyo estado actual sea 1, 2 o 3.

He buscado y leído y probado diferentes variaciones de la consulta pero no lo consigo.

Gracias!

Comment: te falta el max???

Comment: @gbianchi fue una de las cosas que probé pero no obtuve los resultados deseados y no sabría tampoco dónde ponerlo...

Comment: Enfócate primero en obtener el último estado (`max(fecha)`) de cada presupuesto (`GROUP BY idPresupuesto`).

Comment: Entonces lee sobre funciones de agrupacion... usas group by, justamente para usar esas funciones, y decir que campo queres de la columna...

Comment: @gbianchi si, leí y busqué y probé y por eso vine a consultar. Entiendo la lógica de la operación aunque no consigo llevarlo a sql.

Comment: ahhh ya vi uno de tus problemas.. y es que estas usando mysql.. y ahi tienes primero que aprender de [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)... Luego, con esa informacion, vas a entender un poco mas lo que te esta pasando... primero debes hacer como te dijo Sal, buscar max(fecha)

Comment: @Sal estuve haciendo pruebas y consigo traerme la fecha de la última actualización del estado pero no el ID del estado: siempre me trae el primer estado

Comment: @gbianchi muy interesante el link y activé el `only_full_group_by` y me fuerza a meter todos los campos del `select` en el `group by`... de qué manera me serviría ese modo? Uso MySQL 5.6.51

Comment: Porque ahora te das cuenta que tu group by esta mal, a menos que uses funciones de agregacion... empieza usando un max en la fecha para obtener eso..

Comment: @gbianchi, lo conseguí (creo)

Comment: @Sal, lo conseguí (creo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta consulta me trae los presupuestos cuya fecha de validez haya sido superada y cuyo estado mas reciente sea igual o inferior a 3, o sea, el resultado deseado.

```
select pe.idPresupuesto, max(pe.idEstado) as estado, max(pe.fecha) as fecha
from presupuestos_estado pe
inner join (
    select p.id
    from presupuestos p
    where timediff(p.validez, now()) < 0
) as ppto on ppto.id = pe.idPresupuesto
group by pe.idPresupuesto
having (estado <= 3)
order by pe.idPresupuesto asc
```

Graceas @gbianchi y @Sal

PD: "siento" que tal vez no sea eficiente si hay que hacer el `timediff` para cientos o miles de registros. Sería mas eficiente añadir el campo `idEstadoActual` a la tabla `presupuestos` y comparar contra ese `int`? Sería redundante aunque no tan complicado de mantener...

**Actualización:**

Conforme a la respuesta de David JP que descubrió un fallo en mi consulta salvadora, he llegado a esta nueva consulta:

```
select pe.idPresupuesto, pe.idEstado as estado, pe.fecha, p.validez
from presupuestos_estado pe
inner join (
    select idPresupuesto, max(fecha) as fecha
    from presupuestos_estado
    group by idPresupuesto
) as ppto_estado on ((ppto_estado.idPresupuesto = pe.idPresupuesto) and (ppto_estado.fecha = pe.fecha))
inner join presupuestos p on p.id = pe.idPresupuesto
group by pe.idPresupuesto
having (estado <= 3) and (timediff(p.validez, now()) < 0)
order by pe.idPresupuesto asc
```

El fallo en mi consulta salvadora estaba en que si el presupuesto cambia a un estado inferior, no se muestra dicho estado debido al `max(pe.idEstado)` del `select`. Como no me gusta la sintaxis de `using`, he tenido que incluir `p.validez` en el `select` para poder usarlo en la cláusula `having`.

Comment: No hace falta que hagas el segundo `GROUP BY` para usar un `HAVING`, puedes usar directamente un `WHERE` sin agrupar, pues el primer `GROUP BY` está en una subconsulta. Sobre todo, si no vas a hacer uso de ninguna función de totales. ¿De verdad te parece más legible tu query que la mía sólo por el `USING`? En cuanto le hagas la simplificación que te propongo serán idénticas, salvo por su estética. Recuerda que, si no hay ambigüedad posible, no es necesario especificar las tablas :)

Comment: Y... tengo una preferencia por lo explícito jaja, y tampoco nunca había usado el `using` y ayer estuve leyendo la documentación para comprenderlo bien. Tendré mas consultas similares, veré de ir implementándolo. Necesitaba resolver esta consulta para poder mejorar el código `PHP` donde la uso y poder avanzar. También cuando tenga mas registros haré pruebas de rendimiento. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La solución que propones no devuelve exactamente lo que necesitas, sino el registro con el `idEstado` más alto, de entre aquellos registros que cumplen las otras dos condiciones, que no es necesariamente el último.

Verás a qué me refiero si comparas tu solución con esta otra:

```
SELECT idPresupuesto,idEstado,fecha
  FROM presupuestos_estado JOIN (
    SELECT idPresupuesto,MAX(fecha) fecha
      FROM presupuestos_estado
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(idPresupuesto,fecha)
  JOIN presupuestos ON presupuestos.id=idPresupuesto
  WHERE idEstado IN (1,2,3)
  AND validez<NOW();
```

Con respecto al último, no sabría si buscar la última fecha o el último registro insertado, ¿qué dato sería más fiable?

El resultado es el que indicas que esperas:

```
+---------------+----------+---------------------+
| idPresupuesto | idEstado | fecha               |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+
|             1 |        1 | 2022-06-12 13:45:12 |
|             3 |        2 | 2022-12-26 22:49:06 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Para comprobar que tu consulta funciona como esperas, inserta el siguiente registro:

```
INSERT INTO presupuestos_estado
  (id, idPresupuesto, idEstado, fecha, observaciones)
  VALUES
  (59,3,1,NOW(),'');
```

El último estado del presupuesto 3 es el 1, y no 2, como aparecerá en tu consulta.

Aporto el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE presupuestos(
  id int,
  validez datetime
  );
CREATE TABLE presupuestos_estado(
  id int,
  idPresupuesto int,
  idEstado int,
  fecha datetime,
  observaciones text
  );
INSERT INTO presupuestos (id, validez) VALUES
('1','2022-09-01 11:56:47'),
('2','2022-06-15 13:45:12'),
('3','2022-12-18 07:32:14'),
('13','2022-12-29 11:56:47');
INSERT INTO presupuestos_estado (id, idPresupuesto, idEstado, fecha, observaciones) VALUES
(36,1,1,'2022-06-12 13:45:12',''),
(37,2,1,'2022-06-12 13:45:12',''),
(58,2,6,'2022-12-27 22:05:10','actualización automática'),
(38,3,1,'2022-12-15 07:32:14',''),
(39,3,2,'2022-12-26 22:49:06',''),
(29,13,1,'2022-12-26 11:56:47',''),
(30,13,2,'2022-12-26 12:04:27',''),
(33,13,3,'2022-12-26 13:09:11','');
```

Comment: No veo que compares la fecha de `validez` del presupuesto (tabla `presupuestos`) que es el que determina en primera instancia que registros mirar en la tabla `presupuestos_estado`. Cuando comparo visualmente (en consola) el resultado de mi consulta con los datos de las tablas, veo que si me trae los resultados correctos.

Comment: Tu consulta me trae el ultimo estado de un presupuesto que tenga un `idEstado <= 3`, cuya fecha de cambio de estado siempre será inferior a `now()` por lo que el resultado de tu consulta también es correcto pero no lo que necesito

Comment: Perdona, me había equivocado de fecha, ya he modificado la respuesta para subsanarlo. Para ver las diferencias debes registrar estados que puedan dar errores. Sólo cuando hayas comprobado todos los estados posibles podrás tener la certeza de que no te dejas ningún caso sin contemplar :)

Comment: Claro. Tu consulta me da los mismos resultados que la mía. Este es el `var_dump($resultado)` de la mía: `object(mysqli_result)#12 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) } ` y este el de la tuya: `object(mysqli_result)#12 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) } `. La mía me resulta mas legible o fácil de comprender. Gracias de todas maneras por aportar otro punto de vista!

Comment: Ok, veo que no he explicado con claridad el problema de tu consulta. He ampliado la respuesta con un ejemplo para que veas a qué me refiero. Haz el `INSERT` que propongo, prueba ambas consultas y verás la diferencia.

Comment: aahh... ya veo lo que decis. Aunque por un lado no me gusta la sintaxis del `using`, prefiero que sea mas explícito. Este caso parece simple pero en una consulta mas compleja se me complicaría leerla. Me gustaría afinar mi consulta. Volveremos, volveremos...

Comment: Creo haber llegado a una consulta correcta, conforme a tu observación después del `INSERT INTO presupuestos_estado (id, idPresupuesto, idEstado, fecha, observaciones) VALUES (59,3,1,NOW(),'');` rescatando el orden de los `join`s de tu consulta. Actualizo mi respuesta para incluir la nueva consulta obtenida.