# obtener la cantidad total de transacciones emitidas por cada uno de los clientes, asi como el promedio de sus transacciones

Tags: mysql

Este es l codigo que tengo hasta el momento, pero fuera del hecho de que no esta lo del promedio solo me arroja un dato

```
select concat(nombre, "    ",apellidos) as NombreCliente, a.EmisorID, sum(a.cantidad) as Total
from transacciones,clientes
left join transacciones a on clienteID = a.TransactionID;
```

Comment: Y, ¿por qué debería arrojar más de un dato? Y es que ni siquiera se entiende a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *un dato*, ¿te refieres a una sola fila, a que no suma más de un valor ...? Si no muestras un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que incluya un pequeño set de datos existentes y explicas con claridad el problema es difícil saber lo que quieres lograr. Tampoco se entiende a qué te refieres con *promedio*  ¿? Sólo veo que haces una suma en la consulta, sumar y promediar no es lo mismo. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: Yo puedo asegurar, sin mirar nada, que seguro seguro, esto: clienteID = a.TransactionID esta mal.. ademas que estas poniendo las tablas 2 veces (tu from esta mal) y que ademas por como venis, vas a sufrir [este problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Answer (score -1):

Al utilizar funciones en SQL como SUM(), COUNT(), MAX(), etc. Debes utilizar un agrupador para saber como agrupar esos datos. Por lo general se utiliza el GROUP BY. Lo que te quedaría con el siguiente formato:

```
select concat(c.nombre, "    ",c.apellidos) as NombreCliente, a.EmisorID, /*No es necesario que lo muestres (a.EmisorID)*/ sum(a.cantidad) as Total
from clientes c
left join transacciones a on clienteID = a.TransactionID;
GROUP BY c.nombre, c.apellido, a.EmisorID
```

Por otro lado yo a la suma la haría dentro del Left Join:

```
Select concat(c.nombre, "    ",c.apellidos) as NombreCliente, a.cantidad
from Clientes c
     left join (Select t.EmisorID, SUM(t.cantidad)
                  from Transacciones t
              Group by t.EmisorID) a on c.EmisorID = a.EmisorID
```

Espero te resulte util, saludos!

Comment: La respuesta esta mal en el contexto.. como sabes que no tiene que mostrar emisorID? como sabes que la tabla transacciones tiene EmisorID? suponer la respuesta, sin esperar que OP clarifique su pregunta, no es correcto, las respuestas tienen que ser completas, mira por favor [answer]

Comment: No se si tiene o no que poner el EmisorID pero se lo recomiendo ya que por lo general no suele ser necesario. Se que la tabla transacciones tiene EmisorID porque el mismo lo pone en su consulta "a.EmisorID". A demás de eso estoy dando mi opinion en base a mi experiencia de trabajo, si a el no le sirve el lo dirá. Saludos.