# ¿Cómo mostrar registros por horario determinado?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrarme los registros y empleados asignados durante el turno pero como puedo condicionar que despues de cierto horario ya me muestre los del siguiente turno.

Cuento con 3 turnos

Turno F - 6:00 am - 15:30 pm

Turno R - 15:30 am - 00:00 am

Turno S - 00:00 am - 6:00 am

Y yo tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrar los registros utilizando intervalos de 9.5 hrs pero por ejemplo si lo ejecuto ahorita que en mi pais son las 16:34 pm me muestra parte del registro del turno F y parte del turno R y lo que quiero lograr es que me muestre solo lo del turno R.

```
$sql2 = "select Nombre,Puesto,Imagen,cantidad,user_name, count(*) from empleados,certificaciones,workin,meta,seriales where empleado_id = codigo_persona and Certificacion in ('Montacargas', 'Picker') and employee = codigo_persona 
and type = meta.categoria and user_n = user_name and date_time > date_sub(now(),intervla 9.5 HOUR) group by user_name";

$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
```

La tabla empleado cuenta con la columna `turno` y `user_n` y la tabla seriales incluye la columna `date_time` la cual registra la fecha con hora en que se realizo el movimiento del serial al igual que la columna `user_name` con la cual ligo al usuario de la tabla empleados.

Tabla `Empleados`

```
create table `empleados` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_persona` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Puesto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Categoria` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Departamento` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Turno` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_n` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_Reg` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Imagen` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tabla `Seriales`

```
create table `seriales` (
  `id_serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zone_` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `from_` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `material_num` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `serial_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Si tu problema es la query, no pongas en la pregunta todas las otras cosas que no tienen nada que ver con la query... date_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 9.5 HOUR) eso muestra todos los horarios que son mayores a ahora menos 9.5... no es lo que queres, entonces esta mal tu query... de paso, es muy importante que mires https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: Entonces me estas recomendado que los horarios los agrupe por turno y asi ya clasificados mostrarlos y pongo lo demas para que se den una idea de como estoy obteniendo los resultados.

Comment: yo no te recomende nada.. te marque tu error, pero el resto me marea, porque tu problema es un query...

Comment: Puede que el servidor tenga un timezone distinto del de tu país, para comprobarlo puedes ejecutar la siguiente consulta: `SELECT NOW(),@@system_time_zone AS timezone;` si verificas que son diferentes, entonces debes establecer el timezone de tu país antes de ejecutar la consulta. Por otra parte, evita redactar todo en mayúscula, es de mal gusto, considera usar mayúsculas / minúsculas adecuadamente en la redacción de la pregunta, incluyendo el título.

Comment: Es imposible responder esta respuesta, que en realidad es de SQL, sin tener clara la estructura de las tablas y si hay una tabla que almacene los turnos, por ejemplo, o no. Hay que tener en cuenta que no todos los turnos tienen la misma duración.

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta quitando todo el codigo php y dejando solo lo importante del query, agregando las tablas `empleados` y tabla `seriales`.

Comment: Yo habia pensado en un usar un if con 2 else en el cual dependiendo el turno se realizara la consulta utilizando between ya con el rango de los horarios de cada turno pero siento que se vera demasiado mal hacerlo asi por eso acudi aqui para pedir ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a dividir el problema en *partes* y las vamos a ir resolviendo una a una, tal como nos dijo el *profe* algún día en nuestro primer curso de programación o de sistemas informáticos.

Así, primero me voy a enfocar en cómo determinar cuál es el Turno de la hora en curso. Se me ocurre que puedo lograrlo con una sentencia case comparando la hora actual con las horas de inicio y fin de cada turno.

Tomaremos en cuenta aquí que los turnos no pueden traslaparse, por lo que en realidad terminarán un segundo antes de la hora descrita en la pregunta.

```
select case 
         when cast(now() as time) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' then 'S'
         when cast(now() as time) between '06:00:00' and '15:29:59' then 'F'
         else 'R'
       end TurnoHoraActual
```

Me daría entonces S, F o R, según corresponda.

En este punto, quisiera acotar que un diseño más robusto tendría una tabla dónde se configuran los turnos. Estas son cosas que tienden a cambiar con el tiempo, o entre una empresa y otra, y tener estos datos *quemados* en el código hacen que el sistema sea difícil de mantener.

Dicho esto, dado que la tabla de empleados tiene una columna llamada turno, puedo utilizar esto para filtrar los empleados que debe retornar mi consulta, que son los empleados que pertenecen al turno actual.

Ya con esto, lo único que falta es *contar* los seriales que tiene cada empleado en la tabla `seriales` para el día de la operación.

Lo haré con una sub-consulta correlacionada, lo que me permitirá listar TODOS los empleados del turno, aún cuando no tengan ningún serial. Para contar solamente los registros del día, filtraremos el empleado y truncaremos el campo date_time (que tiene información de horas), para quedarnos solo con la fecha valiéndonos de la función `cast()` y lo compararemos con el resultado de la función `curdate()` que nos devuelve la fecha de hoy.

Como siempre, el código dice más que mil palabras:

```
select   case 
           when cast(now() as time) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' then 'S'
           when cast(now() as time) between '06:00:00' and '15:29:59' then 'F'
           else 'R'
         end TurnoActual
       , now() FechaYHoraActual
       , id
       , Nombre
       , (select count(1) 
            from seriales
           where seriales.user_name = empleados.user_n
             and cast(date_time as date) = curdate()
         ) CuentaDeSeriales
  from empleados
 where turno = case 
                 when cast(now() as time) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' then 'S'
                 when cast(now() as time) between '06:00:00' and '15:29:59' then 'F'
                 else 'R'
               end 
 order by Nombre;
```

En esta consulta de ejemplo incluyo el cálculo del turno, así como la fecha y hora actual, solo para que pueda comprobarse el funcionamiento, obviamente en una consulta para producción esos datos podrían ser no necesarios.

He preparado un [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jPbMpEq2DaGAvPrDo7EpRG/0) para que puedas probarlo la *solución* en línea.

Ejecútalo a distintas horas y verás cómo varía sus resultados según la hora que es, incluyendo a los empleados de cada turno y sus resultados.

Si quieres incluir solamente a los empleados que han hecho al menos un *serial* puedes quitar la sub-consulta hacer un join entre las tablas, y agrupar por empleado.

Comment: Muchas gracias deja pruebo tu consulta con la mia que tenia para mostrar solo los empleados que han echo seriales

Comment: Muchas gracias tu respuesta me ayudo mucho ya pude obtener lo que deseaba