# ¿Cómo hago para solo agrupar el ID_Articulo de esta consulta si que se pierda el valor de el COUNT y SUM en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo hago para solo agrupar el ID_Articulo de esta consulta si que se pierda el valor de el COUNT y SUM en MySQL?
Esta consulta se trata de cuentas cuantos artículos compro el vendedor y el total de tos los artículos

```
SELECT COUNT(Valor_Vendido) AS compras, SUM(Valor_Vendido) AS comprasC,
     a.ID, s.Valor_Vendido, s.Username_Comprador, s.Tiempo_Fin,
    s.id_subastas, s.ID_Subasta, ss.comision, a.ID_Articulo, a.Nombre, a.Descripcion, a.ID,
    s.Username_Vendedor, s.Valor_Vendido, s.deuda, s.pagototal, u.Nombres as nomc,
    u.Apellidos as apc, u.Direccion, u.Telefono, u2.Nombres,
     u2.Apellidos, u2.Direccion as Dire, u2.Telefono as Tele FROM subasta s 
     INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.Username = s.Username_Comprador 
     INNER JOIN usuario u2 ON u2.Username = s.Username_Vendedor 
     INNER JOIN articulo a ON a.ID_Articulo = s.ID_Articulo 
     INNER JOIN subastas ss ON s.id_subastas = ss.id_subasta
    WHERE s.Estado ='Vendido' AND ss.id_subasta='2' 
    AND s.Username_Comprador='antonio'
```

que da como resultado asi
[image: el conteo de todos los productos junto con el total de todo lo vendido]
pero lo que ocupo es que que me salga el a.ID_Articulo, a.Nombre, a.Descripcion, a.ID, s.Valor_Vendido, por separado para saber que articulo y cuanto costo cada uno por separado ya trate con **GROUP by ID_Articulo ** pero se pierde el resultado de el conteo de todos los productos junto con el precio total de todo lo vendido

```
SELECT COUNT(Valor_Vendido) AS compras, SUM(Valor_Vendido) AS comprasC,
     a.ID, s.Valor_Vendido, s.Username_Comprador, s.Tiempo_Fin,
    s.id_subastas, s.ID_Subasta, ss.comision, a.ID_Articulo, a.Nombre, a.Descripcion, a.ID,
    s.Username_Vendedor, s.Valor_Vendido, s.deuda, s.pagototal, u.Nombres as nomc,
    u.Apellidos as apc, u.Direccion, u.Telefono, u2.Nombres,
     u2.Apellidos, u2.Direccion as Dire, u2.Telefono as Tele FROM subasta s 
     INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.Username = s.Username_Comprador 
     INNER JOIN usuario u2 ON u2.Username = s.Username_Vendedor 
     INNER JOIN articulo a ON a.ID_Articulo = s.ID_Articulo 
     INNER JOIN subastas ss ON s.id_subastas = ss.id_subasta
    WHERE s.Estado ='Vendido' AND ss.id_subasta='2' 
    AND s.Username_Comprador='antonio' GROUP by ID_Articulo;
```

[image: aquí se me los agrupa por artículos pero se pierde el conteo de todos los productos el precio total de todo lo vendido]
no se que consulta puedo hacer u otro elemento para que me ayude hacer esto muchas gracias

Comment: y este problema que tenes, esta descripto [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)