# ¿Por qué un subquery no reconoce columnas de tabla principal pero al usar variables sí?

Tags: php, mysql, zend

Me encuentro realizando una consulta en la cual realizo un subquery con algunos `JOINS`, y requiero usar algunas columnas de la tabla principal para filtrar dentro del subquery.

Realicé un ejemplo más sencillo sobre mi caso para que sea más comprensible, hay varios puntos a tratar:

```
SELECT
 @var1 := t1.col1 as col_alias1,
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2
   INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.col1 = t2.col1 
   AND t3.col2 = @var1 -- uso la variable dentro de AND de inner
   WHERE t2.col1 = 1 
   LIMIT 1
 ) as subquery,
 t1.col5
 FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.col7 = 'prod_code123'
 GROUP BY t1.col8
 HAVING subquery = 0;
```

**Punto 1:** Al ejecutar esta consulta en Mysql workbench funciona, pero al meter esta consulta al framework PHP Zend algunos registros se pierden: específicamente al consultar solo un registro no lo muestra, tengo que hacer doble ejecución de la consulta para que me arroje la row que quiero. Imagino que es porque la primera vez la variable no tiene nada y en la segunda ejecución sí tiene y me arroja la row esperada. En Zend framework 1 ejecuto esta consulta así:

```php
$this->fetchAll($query)->toArray()
```

**Punto 2:** Se preguntarán por qué uso una variable en el subquery en lugar de simplemente usar la columna directo. El detalle es que al dejar así la consulta:

```sql
 SELECT
     t1.col1 as col_alias1,
     (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2
       INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.col1 = t2.col1 
       AND t3.col2 = t1.col1 -- uso la columna directo sin variable dentro de AND de inner
       WHERE t2.col1 = 1 
       LIMIT 1
     ) as subquery,
     t1.col5
     FROM table1 t1
     WHERE t1.col7 = 'prod_code123'
     GROUP BY t1.col8
     HAVING subquery = 0;
```

Al ejecutarla en mi base de datos local funciona sin problemas, pero al ejecutarla en base de datos de producción arroja el siguiente error:

> SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 't1.col1' in 'field list'

No sé si falte una configuración en el servidor de base de datos de producción para que funcione como en mi local. El caso es que solo funciona en producción usando la variable del **punto 1**, donde también hay un detalle.

**Punto 3:** Intenté cambiando el `AND` dentro del `WHERE` y no sobre el `JOIN` así:

```
SELECT
 t1.col1 as col_alias1,
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2
   INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.col1 = t2.col1 
   WHERE t2.col1 = 1 
   AND t3.col2 = t1.col1 -- //Cambie el AND en el WHERE
   LIMIT 1
 ) as subquery,
 t1.col5
 FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.col7 = 'prod_code123'
 GROUP BY t1.col8
 HAVING subquery = 0;
```

Aquí curiosamente al ejecutarla en base de datos de producción ya no arroja el error anterior, pero no funciona correctamente ya que no devuelve nada cuando sí debería hacerlo, por lo cual es forzosamente usar el `AND` dentro del `JOIN`, pero no se puede porque pasa lo del **punto 2**.

Al parecer hay algún problema al usar la columna directa de la tabla principal `"t1"` dentro de condición del `JOIN`, pero al usar `variable` sí funciona, pero sucede lo del **punto 1**.

Hasta este punto ya no sé qué más puedo intentar o si hacen falta algunas configuraciones en el servidor de base de datos de MySql.

Esta es la información del servidor de base de datos de producción:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux

Y en mi local `8.0.25`

Comment: me gustaria poder ver esto aqui: https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler

Comment: tal vez un ejemplo con los datos nos puedan aportar un mejor contexto

Comment: Para empezar, empareja tu version de desarrollo con la de produccion... si no vas a tener este tipo de problemas mil veces...

Comment: ¿Ocurre lo mismo si haces la referencia directa en el WHERE: `WHERE t2.col1=1 AND t3.col2=t1.col1`?

Comment: *Punto 2: Se preguntarán por qué uso una variable en el subquery en lugar de simplemente usar la columna directo. El detalle es que al dejar así la consulta ... al ejecutarla en base de datos de producción arroja el siguiente error ... `Unknown column 't1.col1' in 'field list'`* A ver, tu servidor no es un niño caprichoso. Si te dice que `col1` no existe en `t1` es que no existe. Basta con que hagas un `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;` y revise cómo se llaman las columnas de esa tabla. ¿No te has planteado que quizá en producción la columna se llama de otra manera distinta?

Comment: No se trata de un problema de versiones de la base de datos. [Aquí tienes un fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qJ0TEw-k) en la misma versión de tu entorno y el código funciona perfectamente. Bueno, en la consulta puse las columnas que omitiste en el `GROUP BY`, porque el único error posible en ese código, si las columnas se llaman así, es el de *nonaggregated column*. Cuando usas `GROUP BY` debes poner en el grupo todas las columnas del `SELECT` o usar funciones de agregación como `MAX`, `MIN` etc que indiquen al SGBD cómo manejar los casos en que varios resultados son posibles en el grupo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu comentario y por agregar un ejemplo pràctico, lo acabo de probar, intenta cambiar el `AND t3.col2 = t1.col1 ` en el `INNER`, no en el `WHERE`, y sucede el error `Unknown column 't1.col1' in 'on clause'`, ese `AND` lo necesito en el `INNER` ya que en el `WHERE` no me da el resultado esperado. Pero en ese mismo ejemplo al usar una variable, ya no arroja el error y funciona. Ese es mi problema.

Comment: @Sal exacto, es algo muy peculiar, en el fiddle que @A.Cedano compartió lo puedes probar con lo que mencioné en mi comentario anterior: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qJ0TEw-k), y la versión que utilizo es la `5.7.33`.

Comment: Ya, pero es que ahí estás en una sub-consulta, si quieres hacer de nuevo `JOIN` dentro de la subconsulta tendrás que indicarlo con algo como `INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t3.col2 = t1.col1 `. [Revisa el fiddle modificado](https://dbfiddle.uk/fA1c7py5). La última consulta tiene ese `JOIN` con `t1` que te menciono. Pero **ese no es el problema**, y no hace falta ese `JOIN`, el `AND` basta. El problema **está en tus datos** no en la consulta.

Comment: Tu consulta es invalida. Tienes un `GROUP BY col8`, pero tienes `col1` y `col5` en to `SELECT`. Para un valor en col8 pueden existir muchos valores en col1 y col5. Entonces, ¿cual col1 y cual col5 debe seleccionar el DBMS para un col8? No lo dijiste al DBMS, y por eso la consulta es invalida. MySQL debería contestar con un mensaje de error, pero obviamente no lo hace. Esto indica que usas MySQL en un modo de fulleria (que desgraciadament existe en MySQL).

Comment: Siempre usa MySQL con el sql_mode `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`. Sin este modo, MySQL cambia col1 y col5 a `ANY_VALUE(col1)` y `ANY_VALUE(col5)` y entonces tus resultados son aleatorios. Entonces: Pone modo 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', arregla tu consulta, y probablemente no vas a tener resultados que te sorprenden. Por cierto: `LIMIT 1` es redundante. `COUNT(*)` sin `GROUP BY` siempre resulta en una sola fila.

Comment: *"ya que en el WHERE no me da el resultado esperado"* ¿Cuál resultado esperas?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que tu consulta es inválida. Y por eso recibes indeseados y errores.

Hay una regla en SQL que es suficiente de agrupar la llave de una table para accesar todos sus campos. Ejemplo:

```
    select a.id_autor, a.nombre, count(c.id_libro)
    from autor a
    left outer join libro l on l.id_autor = a.id_autor
    group by a.id_autor, a.nombre;
```

Es suficiente escribir:

```
    select ...
    group by a.id_autor;
```

porque id_autor is la llave de la tabla autor, y entonces es claro cual nombre de mostrar - el nombre del autor; un autor solamente tiene un nombre. Pero hay situaciones en los cuales es mucho más difícil reconocer que un campo o un grupo de campos forma(n) una llave. En los principios de MySQL era una tarea demasiado difícil para los productores. Y por eso decidían: Tienes que poner el nombre en `GROUP BY` o poner MySQL en un modo de indiferencia, así que no controla la validad de tu consulta con `GROUP BY`. (Hoy en día no es necesario. Al contrario: Es una mala idea usar MySQL en ese modo añoso todavía.)

En tu consulta tienes

```
SELECT col1, ..., col5
...
GROUP BY col8;
```

La cláusula `GROUP BY` dice que quieres una agregación de los datos que debe resultar en una fila por cada valor en col8. Aquí hay dos posibilidades:

1. col8 es la llave de la tabla. Pero en este caso no necesitas el `GROUP BY`. Remuévelo, y toda va a funcionar.
2. col8 no es la llave de la tabla. Entonces cuál col1 y cuál col5 hay que mostrar por un valor en col8. Un valor en col8 puede tener muchos valores diferentes de col1 y col5 en la tabla. El DBMS tiene que contestar con un mensaje de error, pero no lo hace. ¿Por qué no? Porque has puesto tu MySQL en modo de indiferencia.

Parece que la opción #2 es tu situación. MySQL debe que estar en modo `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` para prohibir cláusulas inválidas de `GROUP BY`. Tu MySQL no está en este sql_mode, y entonces no hay no comprobación de la cláusula `GROUP BY`. Lo que hace MySQL en esta situación es "arreglar" las cosas para ti. Así que no dijiste al DBMS cuál col1 y col5 de seleccionar, MySQL asume que no importa y convierte tu cláusula de `SELECT` a

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(col1), ..., ANY_VALUE(col5)
```

Es decir, tus resultados son aleatorios. Además, usas col1 en la subconsulta.

- Usando col1 en `WHERE` funciona: MySQL toma `ANY_VALUE(col1)` y produce un resultado aleatorio.
- Usando col1 en `ON` no funciona: parece MySQL no tiene no mecanismo de aplicar `ANY_VALUE` a una cláusula `ON`. Entonces el error "Unknown column col1 in field list"
- Usando un variable funciona: MySQL usa `ANY_VALUE(col1)` para llenar la variable y toma esa para ejecutar la subconsulta.

La solución:

1. Tienes que pensar sobre lo que quieres hacer. No puedes seleccionar *el* valor col1 para un valor col8. Puedes seleccionar *un* valor, por ejemplo `MAX(col1)` o `MIN(col1)`.
2. Nunca uses el modo de indiferencia. Siempre usa el modo `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` en MySQL.
3. Escribe la consulta que realmente quieres escribir con otro `GROUP BY` o sin `GROUP BY` o con otro `SELECT`.

Comment: mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359) mia.. y si quieres, agrega esta misma respuesta ahi... es muy buena...

Comment: MySQL implementa *Detección de Dependencias Funcionales*; aunque tu respuesta especula sobre la dependencia de `col8` (`{col8} -> {col1}`) siendo que no tenemos la estructura de la tabla, ni sabemos si el resultado inesperado ocurre en una columna no agregada.

Comment: @Sal: Si. La Detección de Dependencias Funcionales es lo que trato de explicar en mi contesta. Hoy en día MySQL sabe hacerlo. En los primeras versiones no era así. Parece que valle50 todavía usa el modo de indeferencía que establecían en el principio que permite ambos: escribir consultas con dependencia funcional y consultas defectuosas. Los problemas con las consultas sugeren que col8 no es una llave unica. Entonces hay que cambiar el modo a `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` para que el DBMS ayuda y detecta el error, y luego hay que cambiar la consulta.